# how to get multiple row values having same id

Tags: php

//controller

```
  public function viewone($billno = NULL) 
  {
  if(empty($this->data)) {
  $this->data= $this->Bill->read(NULL, $billno);    
    } 
  $view = $this->Bill->find('all',array(
    'conditions'=>array('Bill.id =' => $billno)));
  print_r($view);
```

i have passed a billno i.e 6 ,it was giving the values which is having billno 6 details like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Bill] => Array ( [id] => 6 [billno] => 06 [name] => sai [date] => 2015-08-27 [category] => tracks [subcategory] => short [qty] => 1 [amount] => 1100 [dis] => 60 [total] => 1040 [cash] => phani ) ) )
```

but in my database ther is another row with same billno 6 ,i want to get that row details also .
 How to get multiple row details having common billno?

Comment: i got my mistake ,sorry for this silly question

Comment: public function viewone($billno = NULL) 
  {
  if(empty($this->data)) {
  $this->data= $this->Bill->read(NULL, $billno);    
    } 
  $view = $this->Bill->find('all',array(
    'conditions'=>array('Bill.billno =' => $billno)));
  print_r($view);